# A php photo contest with rating system

Tags: php, photo, rating

I would need a simple php photo contest system with rating option. Every user can register on it and upload his photo. Every user can rate the photos (obviously one rate per photo). I don't pretend to find anything which adheres perfectly to my specification, but something similar may be good, as I can hack  and adapt it to my needs.
Can anyone suggest me an existing open-source php project?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry...question edited...thank you

Comment: www.hotornot.com?  There goes your productivity for the day.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically sounds like a hotornot script. Depending on exactly how much control you want to have and what power you want to give the users, there are hundreds of ways to implement it yourself and plenty of scripts already made that will do what you want.

Try http://destiney.com/php#Destiney_rated_images

Comment: Oh thank you! Infact it just sounds like a hotornot script...but before I didn't know the excat jargon...I will give it a look.